# Difference between NSString *const and const NSString *?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, constants

Can someone tell me the difference between the following 2 declarations of NSString?

```
NSString *const userName = @"ABC";
```

and

```
const NSString *userName = @"ABC";
```

Answer (score 0):

The first is a constant pointer to an NSString object, while the second is a pointer to a constant NSString object.

First - A constant pointer (not modifiable) to an NSString (its value can be modified).
Second - A modifiable pointer to a constant NSString (its value can't be modified).

Comment: that's answering without really answering though. Explain how they behave differently...